# MP3 Player Random Function doesn't Work

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I just started my first project and i'm trying to make a mp3 player.
Unfortunately My "Random" causes the whole program to crash when i'm trying to open a song.

This is the error produced in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
```

Please tell me what's wrong with my code, This is a link to my repository in Github, Thanks!

https://github.com/LefanTan/MP3_Player/tree/Mp3

Edit:
This line is the code that was producing the error-

```
Private Sub wpm_PlayStateChange(sender As Object, e As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles wpm.PlayStateChange While shuffle.CheckOnClick = True tempInt = r.Next(0, ListBox1.Items.Count + 1) wpm.URL = ListBox1.Items(tempInt) End While While RepeatToolStripMenuItem1.CheckOnClick = True wpm.URL = currentSong End While End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the actual code here, and (if possible) point out the line the error appears in.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is the problematic sub:

```
 Private Sub wpm_PlayStateChange(sender As Object, e As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent) Handles wpm.PlayStateChange
        While shuffle.CheckOnClick = True
            tempInt = r.Next(0, ListBox1.Items.Count + 1)
            wpm.URL = ListBox1.Items(tempInt)
        End While
        While RepeatToolStripMenuItem1.CheckOnClick = True
            wpm.URL = currentSong
        End While
    End Sub
```

The line

```
tempInt = r.Next(0, ListBox1.Items.Count + 1)
```

Should be

```
tempInt = r.Next(0, ListBox1.Items.Count)
```

The syntax of this function is Random.Next(min, max) where min is inclusive and max is exclusive i.e. max isn't included in generating the random number. Because you added one to ListBox1.Items.Count (which is going to be the upper bound of the collection plus one), you went out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your iteration code.

think the problem is, that your index increases

```
For Each item As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(txtfolder.Text, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.mp3")
                ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
            Next
```